# Paper.js Creating points from ajax response

Tags: jquery, paperjs

I'm using paper.js to allow users to draw lines and then auto smooth them to save them in my database

When I query my DB i get the results in this shape : 
     ["96,426;180,504;246,534;414,516;432,450;"]

Which is one single path with multiple points/segments

Following jquery code

```
$.each(res,function(index,value){
    var path = new paper.Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'white';                 
    var p_ = value;
    //turn path into segments
    var segments = p_.split(';');                                       
    segments = jQuery.grep(segments,function(n,i){
            return (n !== "" && n != null);
    })                                              
    var x;
    var y;                                                                  
    $.each(segments,function(index,value){
        var p_ = value.split(',');
        x = p_[0];
        y = p_[1];
        console.log(x + " " + y);
        var point_ = new paper.Point(x,y);                                          
        console.log(point_);
        path.add(point_);
    })
path.smooth();
paper.view.draw();          
})
```

The conole log line 'console.log(x+" " +y); shows the correct x and y values

When I create a point of those values and console.log the point it returns x=0,y=0

Why is the point not taking the values and using the values?

Comment: It should work, can you provide a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

You're splitting a string into smaller strings. The Point constructor expects an integer or float. Since the position arguments are invalid, it sets them to zero.

Try

```
x = parseFloat(p_[0]);
```